# Was Jesus sentenced twice by Pilate?

Tags: life-of-jesus, crucifixion, pilate, passion

We see in Luke 23:22 how Pilate states that he did not find it justifiable to award death sentence to Jesus and would therefore let him off after giving a punishment. Though Luke does not state what punishment was in the mind of Pilate, Jn 19:1 specifies that Jesus was flogged.John goes on to state that Pilate tried to release Jesus, but later gave in to the pressure made by the Jewish leaders who had started blackmailing him by taking Caesar's name. Now, we see Jesus dying earlier than was anticipated, presumably on account of the severe scourging . It is doubtful if crucifixion as a punishment was generally  preceded by scourging. The fact that some  convicts stayed on the cross for days on end before succumbing to loss of blood and breath, proves otherwise. Reading things together , one can assume that flogging was an additional punishment , that could have been avoided in Jesus' case, given that the Jewish leaders had been demanding crucifixion for him. My question therefore is: Was Jesus sentenced twice by Pilate ? Inputs from scholars of any denomination are welcome.

Comment: Jesus did not die on account of the flogging, nor on account of crucifixion. Jesus states _I lay down my life, that I might take it again. No man taketh it from me, but I lay it down of myself._ John 10:17, 18. Jesus 'gave up the spirit' or 'expired' according to the evangelists' accounts. Pilate had Jesus flogged _in order to present him as a source of pity_ that the Jews might have compassion and be satisfied with a flogging. They were not. They demanded his death.

Comment: Nigel J, you appear to suggest that Jesus chose for himself, the exact time of his death. But, he had surrendered to the Father' s Will and was ready to drink the cup of suffering to the dregs ! (Isiah 51:17 )

Comment: I do not see that Isaiah 51:17 conflicts against the references (to the evangelists' records)  in my previous comment. The sufferings of Jesus Christ (for sins, in the bearing of them 'in his body on the tree') occurred _prior to death_. Once that ended ('It is finished !') he 'gave up the spirit' and 'expired'. After death, the lance pierced his side and then flowed out blood and water.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.